# AppDomainUnloadedException using MAF (Microsoft Addin Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, maf, system.addin

I'm having a AppDomainUnloadedExcpetion from time to time on some machines when calling an addin hosted using MAF (System.AddIn). This is what my pipeline looks like:

```
[AddInContract] 
public interface IGatewayV2 : IContract
{
     ITopUpResultContract TopUpPhoneAccount(ITopUpRequestContract request);
}
```

This is my Host Adapter:

```
[HostAdapterAttribute()]
public class GatewayContractToViewHostSideAdapter : Dogs.Pipeline.HostView.IGatewayV2
{
    private Dogs.Pipeline.Contracts.IGatewayV2 _contract;
    private ContractHandle _handle;

    public GatewayContractToViewHostSideAdapter(Dogs.Pipeline.Contracts.IGatewayV2 contract)
    {
        _contract = contract;
        _handle = new ContractHandle(contract);
    }

    public TopUpResult TopUpPhoneAccount(TopUpRequest request)
    {
        var topupRequestViewToContractHostSideAdapter = new TopUpRequestViewToContractHostSideAdapter(request);

        return
            new TopUpResultContractToViewHostSideAdapter(
                _contract.TopUpPhoneAccount(topupRequestViewToContractHostSideAdapter));

    }
}
```

always on the host adapter side I have a topupRequestViewToContractHostSideAdapter:

```
class TopUpRequestViewToContractHostSideAdapter : ContractBase, ITopUpRequestContract
{
    private TopUpRequest _topUpRequest;

    public TopUpRequestViewToContractHostSideAdapter(TopUpRequest topUpRequest)
    {
        this._topUpRequest = topUpRequest;
    }

    //properties here
)
```

and a TopUpResultContractToViewHostSideAdapter which handles the reference to the external appdomain:

```
  public class TopUpResultContractToViewHostSideAdapter : TopUpResult
  {
    private ITopUpResultContract _contract;
    private ContractHandle _handle;

    public TopUpResultContractToViewHostSideAdapter(ITopUpResultContract contract)
    {
        this._contract = contract;
        _handle = new ContractHandle(contract);
    }

    //properties here
  }
```

On the addin side instead I have the following code:

```
[AddInAdapter()]
public class GatewayViewToContractAddInSideAdapter : ContractBase, Dogs.Pipeline.Contracts.IGatewayV2
{
    private Dogs.Pipeline.AddinViewV2.IGatewayV2 _view;

    public GatewayViewToContractAddInSideAdapter(Dogs.Pipeline.AddinViewV2.IGatewayV2 view)
    {
        this._view = view;
    }

    public ITopUpResultContract TopUpPhoneAccount(ITopUpRequestContract request)
    {
        var result = _view.TopUpPhoneAccount(new TopUpRequestContractToViewAdapter(request));
        return new TopUpResultViewToContractAdapter(result);
    }
}
```

where the TopUpResultViewToContractAdapter is:

```
public class TopUpResultViewToContractAdapter : ContractBase, ITopUpResultContract
{ 
    private TopUpResult _topUpResult;

    public TopUpResultViewToContractAdapter(TopUpResult result)
    {
        this._topUpResult = result;
    }

    //properties here
}
```

and the TopUpRequestContractToViewAdapter is:

```
public class TopUpRequestContractToViewAdapter : TopUpRequest
{
    private ITopUpRequestContract _contract;
    private ContractHandle _handle;

    public TopUpRequestContractToViewAdapter(ITopUpRequestContract contract)
    {
        _contract = contract;
        _handle = new ContractHandle(contract);
    }

    //properties here
}
```

Everything seems compliant with what I've read so far and in particular with what I can read at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384186(v=vs.100).aspx
So I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or there is a possibility that the pipeline doesn't work on certain machines (as I'm having problem not on all the machines I'm using for testing).

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: How are you activating the AddIns?  If it is in process as a separate app domain, then you can attach to the AppDomainUnhandledException

Comment: @g.cacciapaglia - did you ever solve this? Having a similar issue!

Comment: No, I moved to another company and until then the problem was still there. Anyway I would strongly advise against using MAF as it seems that even Microsoft is not giving any consideration to this framework (I suppose it is still there because of backward compatibility reasons).